# InfoPath 2007 Print View - Multiple Select Boxes

Tags: infopath

I have an InfoPath form that I will eventually need to print. There needs to be a Multiple-Select box (Selecting up to 20 options). I've poked and prodded around looking for a way to only print / display after submit to a SharePoint document library only the items that have been selected.

I've dabbled in xml a tiny bit, so programmatically doing this is an option though I'd like to stay away from it.

Comment: In SP2010 they provide an option to print from the ribbion view.

Comment: I'm using MOSS 2007.